# How to upload file with Okhttp3 (REST API)

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I'm trying to upload an image with [uploading bytes](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media#uploading-bytes) of Google Photos API .

So here is my request with OkHttp3:

```java
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                .addHeader("Content-type:", "application/octet-stream")
                .addHeader("X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type:",mimeType)
                .addHeader("X-Goog-Upload-Protocol:", "raw")
                .url("https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads")
                .post(requestBody) // how to build request body?
                .build();
```

the documentation says: "In the request body, include the binary of the file:"

> media-binary-data

What does it means?

For a given file, I assume that it is:

```java
byte[] data =  FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(myPath));
```

But how do you build this requestBody with data array?

**EDIT**
I already tried :

```java
MediaType mType = MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8");
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(mType,new File(path));
```

Exception :

> okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: PROTOCOL_ERROR

Thank you in advance for putting me on the track!

Comment: Have you checked out the "recipe" for posting a file? - https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#posting-a-file-kt-java

Answer (score 1):

`RequestBody` has a few overloaded factory methods:

- [create(MediaType, byte[])](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/RequestBody.html#create-okhttp3.MediaType-byte:A-)
- [create(MediaType, File)](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/RequestBody.html#create-okhttp3.MediaType-java.io.File-)

It looks like you're supplying the second parameter in either case correctly.

As for the `MediaType` parameter, I usually use the MIME type of the underlying image rather than specifying general binary content, e.g.:

```
MediaType.parse("image/jpeg")
   or
MediaType.parse("image/png")
   ...
```

Comment: I already tested all this tricks...I obtained PROTOCOL ERROR each time :(

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately I left the ":" after the parameter keys !!!!

```java
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                .addHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream")// and no X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type :
                .addHeader("X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type",mimeType)//same
                .addHeader("X-Goog-Upload-Protocol", "raw")//same
                .url("https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads")
                .post(requestBody) 
                .build();
```

And for the requestBody:

```java
byte [] data =  FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(mimeTypeOfFile,data);
```